# Extending NgFor results in duplicate output

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

Referencing this custom Angular 2 directive (which extends NgFor) in a component, and then using an NgFor on the page, results in duplicate enumeration:

```
import {
    Directive,
    ChangeDetectorRef,
    IterableDiffers,
    ViewContainerRef,
    TemplateRef,
    ElementRef
} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NgFor } from '@angular/common';
import { NgForRow } from './ngForRow';

import { AppComponent } from '../../app.component';

@Directive({
    selector: '[ngTreeLeaf][ngTreeLeafOf]',
    inputs: [
        'ngTreeLeafOf',
        'ngTreeLeafTemplate',
        'ngTreeLeafRoute'
    ]
})
export class NgTreeLeaf extends NgFor {
    private _routePattern: RegExp;

    constructor(
        viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
        templateRef: TemplateRef<NgForRow>,
        iterableDiffers: IterableDiffers,
        cdr: ChangeDetectorRef,
        private _router: Router,
        private _elementRef: ElementRef) {
        super(viewContainer, templateRef, iterableDiffers, cdr);
    }

    set ngTreeLeafOf(leaves: Array<any>) {
        this.ngForOf = leaves;
    }

    set ngTreeLeafRoute(route: string) {
        this._routePattern = new RegExp(route + "\\b", "g");
    }

    set ngTreeLeafTemplate(value: TemplateRef<NgForRow>) {
        this.ngForTemplate = value;
    }

    isLeafActive(urlString: string) {
        if (!this._router || !this._routePattern) return false;
        let active = this._routePattern.test(this._router.url);
        if (active) {
            this._elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement.classList.add("active");
        }
        else {
            this._elementRef.nativeElement.parentElement.classList.remove("active");
        }
        return active;
    }
}
```

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34325619/608220) mentions, annotations aren't inherited, so I'm not sure where it's getting the motive to apply my code additionally. I assume it has to either be the parent class name interacting with DI, or a combination of DoCheck being discovered and a variable that is somehow shared. But I don't see the issue right offhand.

Any suggestions? Also seems [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34887196/608220) like I wouldn't expect this trouble.